# Multi app architecture and databases

Tags: laravel, architecture, multiple-databases

I have just developped a Human Ressource WebApp in Laravel.

So in this app, I have my user database.

Now, I have 2 old apps, that I'm about to rewrite / Migrate to Laravel.

The first one is to manage employee payments.

The second app is for monitoring my salesforce in field.

So, Basically, I will basically rewrite them.

My Question is about architecture. I will develop those 2 apps separating APIs in Lumen / Laravel for each app, individually, and then writing  clients in Angular2.

I will use OAuth2.0 to set authorization and scopes between apps.

Now, My indecision resides on Database part.

Should I keep database separated, include database in the same schema, or how should I deal with my databases.

Today, I have 1 DB per app, but also, I have redundancy in users: Each App works with the same users, and so duplicate this info.

Right now, When User is created in App1, it calls APIs to create it in app2 and app3. This is not so nice, IMHO.

So, I think I would like to have a single User Database, but I don't really have experience of that:

- should I extract User's info in a central database for all users, should
- should I keep User's info duplicated between my DB?
- if I keep it in 3 differents DB, how should I make JOINs, transactions, Foreign Keys, etc.

I know there is not 1 answer, it depends of what I want, but this is also my problem, I don't know which question should I be asking to make my decision???

It is important to mention that I don't have so much traffic, max 1000 users, and they all belongs to my enterprise, it will not increase to much. So, really, make a scallable app should not be my priority right now.

Any Advice will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have shared databases between your apps, the common practice is to have it in the same Laravel/Lumen app.

The way you can achieve this is separating the apps inside route groups, namespacing the controllers hierarchies of each app and declaring inside each model the connection you will be using for this model.

This way you can use the same DB connections for all of your apps, and share the same data without the need of duplicating it.